# My (new) pc is not ready for Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I've just installed all the parts:

- Asus B560 motherboard
- Intel I5 11500
- 16 GB ram
- Geforce 1060
- 500 GB NVME drive (mounted on the motherboard)

And it states during install that its not Windows 11 ready? What the haaail :-). The 1060 card is a bit older, but still has DirectX 12. The CPU is brand spanking new and has the TPM 2.0 chip

Comment: Can you provide more specific information on what errors you have received?  Microsoft has a tool to determine the reason your machine might not be ready for Windows 11.  Have you used that tool to determine what the reason might be?  You can [edit] your question to allow a more specific answer to be submitted.

Comment: Okey, after franticly googling around I found out that my motherboard did not have the right setting. This might apply to others who buy new motherboards so I'll link to the video below that explained it for me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p83oY2RcIs8

Answer (score 3):

Windows 11 requires 4 things at the minimum:  UEFI and GPT instead of legacy BIOS, Secure Boot enabled, TPM2 and a processor (CPU) less than 3 years old.

You say new processor - that should work.
You say it has a TPM2 chip - that should work.

So make sure the drive is formatted for GPT and that the system uses UEFI (3 partitions:  UEFI, Recovery and your main partition).

Make sure Secure Boot is enabled in BIOS.

That should work.

You can run the Microsoft PC Health Check and also the GitHub "Whynotwin11"  to produce a checklist of your PC.

I use Whynotwin11  myself. The screen shot below is from my X1 machine and the CPU generation is too old.

[image: WhyNotWin11]

I just purchased a new Windows 10 Pro computer: UEFI, Secure Boot, TPM2, and 10th generation Intel CPU. Update says it is ready for Windows 11.

I change the main drive (much bigger now), used the Lenovo Recovery USB key to re-image the computer and I allowed it to update to Windows 11 Pro - running now.

[image: Win 11 Production]

Comment: And make sure the TPM is actually ENABLED in UEFI. Many motherboards have it disabled by default.